# Flask returns variable as text with quotes instead as html element

Tags: flask, jinja2

i am trying to insert to a jinga template a html text which will be submited as variable from the python script

Python:

```
@app.route('/faq', defaults={'faq_id': "keine_id"})
@app.route('/faq/<string:faq_id>')
def faq(faq_id):
    return render_template('faq.html', beschreibung=f"<p>{data['beschreibung']}</p>")
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
        <div class="single_product_desc">
            <div class="product-meta-data">
                <p class="product-price">{{titel}}</p>
            </div>
            {{ beschreibung }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

If i visit the webpage the webpage loads my variable as text not as html code, instead there are just quotes arround my text and the paragraph tags get ignored:
[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the jinja2 filter ["safe"](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=safe#safe) to suppress the automatic escaping.

```
{{ beschreibung | safe }}
```

Comment: With this method OP should be careful `data['beschreibung']` doesn't contain unvalidated user input.  If an attacker is able to get something like a `<script>` tag in there, then they could execute any JS on the frontend.

Comment: @v25 is correct. You should validate the input and possibly perform the escaping yourself. See [following](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.escape).

Comment: alright, thank you guys!